# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dio

I'm trying to fetch data from FastAPI and feed it to my handle logic for binding into card view but I keep getting the following error:

```
// When toList() is not applied: 
type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Place>' 

// When toList() is applied:  
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

I have checked a couple of other posts on Stackoverflow like my code but they do not apply to my situation.

How should I change my code?

This is input data: JSON format (from FastAPI)

```
{
    "status_code": 200, 
    "status_msg": "ok", 
    "data": [{
            "id": 12, 
            "name": "name1", 
            "images": ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"], 
            "description": "description1", 
            "location": "address1",  
            "likes": 16700, 
            "comments": 10,  
        }, 
             {
            "id": 13, 
            "name": "name2", 
            "images": ["img4.jpg", "img5.jpg", "img6.jpg"], 
            "description": "description1", 
            "location": "address1",  
            "likes": 190002, 
            "comments": 9,  
        } 
    ] 
}
```

Model class

```
class Place {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  List<String>? images;
  String? description;
  String? location;  
  int? likes;
  int? comments; 

  Place(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.images,
      this.description,
      this.location, 
      this.likes,
      this.comments });

  factory Place.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Place(
        id: json['id'] ?? '',
        name: json['name'] ?? '',
        images: json['images'] ? null : json['images'],
        description: json['description'] ?? '',  
        likes: json['likes'],
        comments: json['comments']); 
  }
}
```

This is flutter code for handling data from API calls:

```
Future getData() async {
    List<Place> _data = [];
    List<Place> get data => _data;

    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? uid = sp.getString('uid');
    if (uid == null) uid = 'system'; 
    final params = <String, dynamic>{
      'uid': uid,
      'curr_loc': '',
      'flag': 'P',
      'top_k': 5
    };

    final _resp = await dio.get(
      Config().baseAPIURL + '/api_name',
      queryParameters: params,
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          "authorization": Config().APIToken,
        },
      ),
    );

    if (_resp.data["status_code"] == 200) {
      _data = _resp.data["data"].map((x) => Place.fromJson(x)).toList(); // <--- Error raised in here 
    } else {}
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Tried adding a .toList()?

Comment: I've already tried your suggestion, but still remains the following error.  type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Comment: I think you can try `List.from`

Comment: You mean:  _data = List.from(_resp.data["data"]);  or  _data = List.from( _resp.data["data"]).map((x) => Place.fromJson(x)));  // Unfortunately still keep getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests a type inconsistency between the expected `List<Place>` type and the actual data received from the API.

The error you're facing with `MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>` indicates that the mapping operation is returning a different type than `List<Place>`. Similarly, the error with `List<dynamic>` being a subtype of `bool` suggests that the type conversion is not happening as expected.

Let's refine your `fromJson` method in the `Place` class to handle the image list parsing and make sure the data mapping from the API response to `List<Place>` is correctly typed.

Try updating your `Place` class `fromJson` factory method as follows:

```
factory Place.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Place(
    id: json['id'] ?? 0,
    name: json['name'] ?? '',
    images: (json['images'] as List<dynamic>).cast<String>(), // Cast images to List<String>
    description: json['description'] ?? '',
    location: json['location'] ?? '',
    likes: json['likes'] ?? 0, 
    comments: json['comments'] ?? 0,

  );
}
```

This update should properly cast the dynamic list of images to a `List<String>`.

Then, when mapping the API response to `List<Place>` in your `getData` function:

```
if (_resp.data["status_code"] == 200) {
  _data = (_resp.data["data"] as List<dynamic>)
      .map((x) => Place.fromJson(x))
      .toList();
} else {
  // Handle other status codes or errors if needed
}
```

By explicitly casting `_resp.data["data"]` to `List<dynamic>` before mapping it to Place, you ensure that the conversion to `List<Place>` happens correctly.

This should resolve the type mismatch issue when parsing the JSON data into a list of `Place` objects.

Comment: Awesome!! You brightened my day!! Thank you soooooooooo much!

Comment: @ChrisJoo accept his answer using that check button!!